# Geolocation not working on Local

Tags: sxa, personalization, tracking, geo-location

I have configured a page for personation based on `GeoIP` but it doesn't work on my local. I have used a chrome extension to fake IP address. I can see `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.Ip` and it is being set as expected.
I have below configuration set as

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true"/>
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true"/>
<setting name="Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader" value="X-Forwarded-For"/>
```

What I am missing here.

Comment: To verify GeoIP service activated and subscribed, check details at https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html

To test GeoIP check the Solution-3 https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498

Comment: Thank you @AmitKumar there was no subscription so it didn't work.

Comment: As @Amit Kumar pointed out, I had not subscribe for GeoIP service. After subscribing, it worked.